# Keepalived with apache unable to bind interface on Backup server

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, keepalived, listener

I have two debian 6 servers running keepalived 1.1.20 with one server acting as a Master and the other as a Backup. Both servers host apache 2.4 that have a global Listener on all interfaces on port 80 (Listen *:80) how ever I have some sites that require a listener for port 443 (SSL) and that is configured for each VirtualHost in the Apache config since I do not want every VirtualHost to listen on port 443.

The problem is when I try to start Apache on the Backup machine that does not hold the virtual interface the VirtualHost is supposed to be listening on, I get `AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 1.1.1.1:443`. I know this is expected behavior of Apache.

The real question is are there any known workarounds or solutions to this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following command as root:

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_nonlocal_bind
```

This enables your applications to be able to bind to an address which doesn't belong to a device on your system. You can set this in `/etc/sysctl.conf` to make it permanent.

Comment: This is certainly a very elegant solution, but I'd like to add that keepalived can also be configured to run scripts when a state transition occurs. This allows for any kind of changes to the services running on a server. See the `notify` commands in `keepalived(5)`.